# 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before dot

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs4, flashdevelop

I'm new to ac3 can you help me please.

getting this error 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before dot.

```
   {}.progress = function (event:ProgressEvent) : void
```

Comment: can't you just create a named object var magic:Object = {}; then magic.progress = function(e:ProgressEvent):void {}; ?

Answer (score 3):

it is kind of mystery why you want to do this in that way, however casting as Object as follows avoids the error

```
({} as Object).progress = function(e:Event):void { };
```

also it is better to have a named object like so:

```
var magic:Object = {};
magic.progress = function(e:ProgressEvent):void {};
```

also if you really want anonymous object:

```
{
    progress:function(e:Event):void
    {}
};
```

best regards

Comment: I have tested all those 3 options in FlashDevelop and it wasn't generating any errors (your version did). You can give more details or more code where you used the problematic syntax.